# Cannot uninstall expo on mac

Tags: expo, package.json, uninstallation

When I try doing "yarn global remove expo-cli" I get this error:

````
[1/2]   Removing module expo-cli...
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.```

I have tried everything from deleting everything that has expo named in my directory. Nothing has seemed to work
````